# Design changes when I switch my browser to and from full-screen

Tags: html, css

When I run this code in my browser (Google Chrome) at 100%,  it is fine. However, when I minimize it, the divs go all over the place. I am not sure whether it is the meta tags, if have I left something out, or if I have included something in my code that should not be there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="public">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="cache">
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">
<meta name="description" content="A Website Designed For Young People To Enjoy Themselves Through Irish">
<meta name="keywords" content="Youth Zone, Crios Óige, Irish, Gaeilge, Irish Videos, Fun with Irish">
<meta name="author" content="Edward Leonard">
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
<meta name="googlebot" content="archive">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Crios Óige | Abhaile</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#009900";>
<div id="divide1">
</div>
<div id="divide2">
</div>
<div id="header">
    <img src="file:///E:/Crios%20Óige/Crios%20Oige%20Images/Logo.png" id="logo">
    <img src="file:///E:/Crios%20Óige/Crios%20Oige%20Images/Title.PNG" id="title">
    <img src="http://www.youtharts.ie/sites/youtharts.ie/files/NYCI%20Logo%20Full%20JPG_2.jpg" id="youthcouncil">
</div>
<div id="toolbar">
    <div id="homebutton">
        <div id="homebuttonlink">
            <b><a href="index.html" id="homebuttonlinkstyle">Abhaile</a></b>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="videosbutton">
        <div id="videosbuttonlink">
            <b><a href="videos.html"; id="videosbuttonlinkstyle">Fiseán</a></b>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="imagesbutton">
        <div id="imagesbuttonlink">
            <b><a href="images.html"; id="imagesbuttonlinkstyle">Pictiúir Greannmhar</a></b>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="gamesbutton">
        <div id="gamesbuttonlink">
            <b><a href="games.html"; id="gamesbuttonlinkstyle">Cluichí</a></b>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sportbutton">
        <div id="sportbuttonlink">
            <b><a href="sport.html"; id="sportbuttonlinkstyle">Spórt</a></b>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contactusbutton">
        <div id="contactusbuttonlink">
            <b><a href="contactus.html"; id="contactusbuttonlinkstyle">Déan teagmháil linn</a></b>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="aboutus">
    <div id="aboutustitle">
        <p id="aboutustitlestyle">Maidir Linne</p>
    </div>
    <p id="aboutuscontent">***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the accompanying CSS

```
body {
text-align: justify;
}
a {
text-decoration: none;
}
a:link {
color:#FF0000;
}    /* unvisited link */
a:visited {
color:#4D0000;
} /* visited link */
a:hover {
color:#0000FF;
}   /* mouse over link */
a:active {
color:#FF0000;
}  /* selected link */
#header {
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #993333;
margin-top: -10px;
}
#toolbar {
height: 151px;
width: 51.29%;
background-color: #FF0000;
position: relative;
top: -10px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
#homebutton {
height: 80px;
width: 27%;
background-color: #0000FF;
position: relative;
top: -19px;
margin: 21px;
float: left;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
#videosbutton {
height: 80px;
width: 27%;
background-color: #0000FF;
position: relative;
top: -19px;
margin: 21px;
float: left;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
#imagesbutton {
height: 80px;
width: 27%;
background-color: #0000FF;
position: relative;
top: -19px;
margin: 21px;
float: left;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
#gamesbutton {
height: 69px;
width: 27%;
background-color: #0000FF;
position: relative;
top: -61px;
margin: 21px;
float: left;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
#sportbutton {
height: 69px;
width: 27%;
background-color: #0000FF;
position: relative;
top: -61px;
margin: 21px;
float: left;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
#contactusbutton {
height: 69px;
width: 27%;
background-color: #0000FF;
position: relative;
top: -61px;
margin: 21px;
float: left;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
#homebuttonlink {
height: 30px;
width: 77%;
background-color: #FFFF00;
position: relative;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
top: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#videosbuttonlink {
height: 30px;
width: 77%;
background-color: #FFFF00;
position: relative;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
top: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#imagesbuttonlink {
height: 30px;
width: 77%;
background-color: #FFFF00;
position: relative;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
top: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#gamesbuttonlink {
height: 30px;
width: 77%;
background-color: #FFFF00;
position: relative;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
top: -6px;
border-radius: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#sportbuttonlink {
height: 30px;
width: 77%;
background-color: #FFFF00;
position: relative;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
top: -6px;
border-radius: 5px;
line-height: -10px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#contactusbuttonlink {
height: 30px;
width: 77%;
background-color: #FFFF00;
position: relative;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
top: -6px;
border-radius: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#contactusbuttonlinkstyle {
font-size: 17px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
line-height: 10px
}
#sportbuttonlinkstyle {
font-size: 30px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
#gamesbuttonlinkstyle {
font-size: 30px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
#imagesbuttonlinkstyle {
font-size: 17px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
line-height: 10px;
}
#videosbuttonlinkstyle {
font-size: 30px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
#homebuttonlinkstyle {
font-size: 30px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
#divide1 {
height: 1291px;
width: 25.125%;
background-color: #330066;
position: relative;
margin: -10px;
float: left;
top: -10px;
}
#divide2 {
height: 1291px;
width: 25.125%;
background-color: #330066;
position: relative;
margin: -10px;
float: right;
top: -10px;
}
#aboutus {
height: 200px;
width: 400px;
margin: 475px;
background-color: aqua;
top: -450px;
position: relative;
border-radius: 10px;
}
#aboutustitle {
height: 40px;
width: 200px;
background-color: red;
position: relative;
margin-left: 100px;
top: 10px;
border-radius: 20px;
}
#aboutuscontent {
word-wrap: break-word; 
margin-left: 20px; 
margin-right: 20px
}
#aboutustitlestyle {
font-size: 20px;
color: yellow;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
margin-left: 40px;
line-height: 35px;
}
#youthcouncil {
height: 80px;
width: 180px;
margin-left: 300px;
margin-top: 5px;
}
#logo {
height: 80px;
width: 180px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 5px;
}
#title{
height: 80px;
width: 180px;
margin-left: 250px;
margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: By minimize, do you mean make the size smaller? Maybe you should look into a responsive design: http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design

Comment: can you make it into a fiddle please

Comment: Just to make sure, but the css you posted is the css that's contained in `stylesheet.css`, right?

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpdurham/k4W7f/) to play with.

Comment: Sorry but what am I supposed to do with a fiddle? I never seen it before.

Comment: Sorry, that was for @173901 who requested a fiddle.  [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) is a site where you can post css, html, and javascript for other people to see and work with.  It is basically an easy way to share code with people.

Comment: @EdwardLeonard, what do you want your page to look like when you're finished?  Do you want everything to stay where it is whether you're in fullscreen mode or not, or do you want elements to be rearranged and resized depending on the size of your screen?

Answer (score 0):

One meta tag you are missing is the viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
```

The other problem is that your design is not responsive. You should use media queries to add breakpoints each time your design breaks. What this basically mean is that you should start minimising your screen (you can use the awesome Chrome's emulation feature for different resolutions and mobile devices) and each time the design starts to break you should add a breakpoint (at this specific width). Inside the breakpoint you will have different css rules that will make the design work for this specific breakpoint.

There are tons of tutorials at this topic, for example:

[Logical Breakpoints For Your Responsive Design](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/01/logical-breakpoints-responsive-design/)

[Setting Breakpoints in Responsive Design](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/setting-breakpoints-in-responsive-design)

**EDIT:**

Another thing I would change in your design - it heavily depends on relative positioning of element. I would use `display: inline-block` or `float: left/right` in order to position the element next to each other. In The places you did use the "display: inline-block" you were using it wrong (inside the inner div element). You should use it on the outer divs (such as "gamesbutton" element and not on "gamesbuttonlink")

Answer (score 0):

You have set many of your elements width to be a dynamic width (using something like `width: 27%` in your css).  Remember that whenever your screen is resized, those elements are also resized proportionately.  If you want your elements to stay the same width regardless of what size the screen is, use `width:100px` for a fixed width.  The same goes for `height`.

If you want a responsive design, you should set your styles using `@media` queries.  See [some common media queries for different devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).  Whenever the conditions of a query is met, those styles are applied.

Comment: So simply do not use percentages and use px

Comment: If you don't want your divs shrinking in size when you make your window smaller, then yes.

Comment: @EdwardLeonard did this help you with your problem?